# how to list values in a row where adjacent cells are blank in excel

Tags: excel

I would like to list the unique DC Nos only on a separate Sheet where the corresponding Invoice No is blank.

Pic for reference:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

You can build a pivot on the dataset in your screenshot, drag in DC no and Invoice no as row labels and filter Invoice no as Blanks. Click this [link](http://fiveminutelessons.com/learn-microsoft-excel/how-create-pivot-table-excel#sthash.VUId9D4Z.dpbs) to understand the basics of pivot tables if you haven't used it before.